# Как передать данные из RecyclerView Adapter в другой фрагмент?

Tags: android-fragment, activity, recyclerview.adapter

Есть активити с двумя фрагментами. В одном из них находится RecyclerView. Есть самописный адаптер в котором при нажатии на элемент он добавляется в массив, который потом должен попасть в RecyclerView второго фрагмента. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать класс Singleton. Записываешь в него информацию с первого фрагмента, и в момент открытия и отрисовки второго фрагмента заполняешь своими данными из Singleton, которые записал в первом фрагменте. Либо записываешь данные в массив и передаешь в параметрах Fragment Transaction.